# Change table contents to match a query without deleting all rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (`tblA`) and a query (`queryB`). The output of `queryB` matches the schema of `tblA`. I want to update `tblA` so that it's contents are equal to `queryB`

An obvious solution to this might be:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tblA

INSERT INTO tblA
(queryB)
```

However, I want to minimise the number of deletes and inserts I do.

There will be three cases with the results from `queryB`:

- In `queryB`, not in `tblA`: Insert
- In `queryB`, in `tblA`: Do Nothing
- In `tblA`, not in `queryB`: Delete

So far I have found the MS SQL's MERGE supports a `[NOT] PRESENT IN TARGET/SOURCE` that would be perfect for this - but have not found an Oracle equivalent.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you thought about using a materialized view? (BTW, what you're doing is optimal in terms of delete operations. Whether doing a merge if that supported deletes would be faster depends a lot on how much of each you're expecting.)

Comment: @Mat I've simplified a little for the Q - I would actually only be inserting for a certain PK (so it would be delete from tblA where id = x). I think it's quite likely that `queryB` will be quite similar to `tblA` so there will likely be many 'do nothings' and only a few 'inserts' and 'deletes' each time.

Comment: hi, "In queryB, not in tblA: Insert" and "In queryB, not in tblA: Delete" don't have the same condition? I don't get when you wanna insert, and when you wanna delete.

Comment: @Dax - Oops! Thanks, have updated answer to reflect what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from tblA where
  (col1, col2, ...) not in (queryB);

insert into tblA 
  (queryB) minus (select * from tblA);
```

---

**EDIT :**
You can calculate queryB once if small temporary table will be created (which will contain < 10% of rows of table tblA).
It is assumed that queryB.col1 is never null

```
create table diff as
   select 
      ta.rowid ta_rid, 
      tb.*
   from tblA ta 
      full join (queryB) tb 
         on ta.col1 = tb.col1 
         and ta.col2 = tb.col2 
         and ta.col3 = tb.col3 
   where 
      ta.rowid is null or tb.col1 is null; 

delete from tblA ta 
  where ta.rowid in (select d.ta_rid from diff d where d.ta_rid is not null);
insert into tblA ta 
  select d.col1, d.col2, d.col3 from diff d where d.ta_rid is null;
```

Comment: If `queryB` is complex how can I not call it twice?

Comment: @AndySmith - Do `queryB` and `tblA` have >90% rows in common?

Comment: It's probable that it often will but I can't guarantee it

Comment: @AndySmith - if they are not so different, than "truncate + insert with append" is the fastest way.

Comment: But if I still didn't want to do it that way - is there a solution?

Comment: Thanks - this looks to be the only way to do it given the constraints